# Query an embedded Spring Data elasticsearch directly over HTTP?

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

Is it possible with Spring Data ES to query an embedded ES directly over HTTP without using the Java Client? 
How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the http parameter true and it works

```
<elasticsearch:node-client  cluster-name="cluster" http-enabled="true" id="cluster"/>
```